# Codeception color report does not work

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, code-coverage, codeception

I have setup codeception to code coverage. I can see the report did run correctly but for some reason code coverage color and percentage did not get calculated.  I do see green line which code get executed but it did not show the red.

I have been pulling my hair out and struggle for several days but not be able to figure out the issue. Please help.
Note my /etc/hosts  have stagwww.somewhere.com  as 127 loop back
my codeception.yml
`actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed`

my api.suite.yml

`class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\Api
        - REST:
            url: https://stagwww.somewhere.com
            depends: PhpBrowser
coverage:
    enabled: true
    remote: true
    low_limit: 30
    high_limit: 60
    c3_url: 'https://stagwww.somewhere.com'
    remote_context_options:
        ssl:
            verify_peer: false
            verify_peer_name : false
    include:
      - app\*.php`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "color" setting in your YML is for ANSI color in the *terminal*. Your screen shot is showing an HTML reporter in the *browser* - I think the Xdebug codecoverage report. I don't think there is such a setting as "color" in the HTML report, it's a totally different interface.

Color:
[image]
No Color:
[image]

Comment: aside from color as you can see the percentage code coverage is also wrong

Comment: I think you should ask that as a seperate question about Xdebug and the codeceverage reporter.